# Javascript Canvas: How to get the specific points on transparent png file?

Tags: javascript, canvas

[image]

Okay, I am confused with get Image Data function for 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData

I have a path image that is in png format with transparent background above. What I need to get are the coordinates x,y for both left and right edges of the path at height/2. (The points of the red arrows)

Is getImageData the right function to use? Can anyone give some advice on how to get them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `getImageData(x, y, width, height);`
 In the case you have only two colors (here transparent & white) :

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = getPoints;
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/lvgvekzkyqkypos/path.png";

function getPoints(){
  // set our canvas
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;
  // draw the image
  ctx.drawImage(this,0,0);
  // get the middle y line
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,Math.floor(this.height/2), this.width, 1);
  var data = imageData.data;
  // set an empty object that will store our points
  var pts = {x1: null, y1: Math.floor(this.height/2), x2: null, y2:Math.floor(this.height/2)};
  // define the first opacity value
  var color = 0;
  // iterate through the dataArray
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i+=4){
    // since we'relooking only for non-transparent pixels, we can check only for the 4th value of each pixel
    if(data[i+3]!==color){
      // set our value to this new one
      color = data[i+3];
      if(!pts.x1)
        pts.x1 = i/4;
      else
        pts.x2 = i/4;
      }
    }
  
  snippet.log('start points : '+pts.x1+'|'+pts.y1);
  snippet.log('end points : '+pts.x2+'|'+pts.y2);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(pts.x1-5, pts.y1, 10, 10);
  ctx.fillRect(pts.x2-5, pts.y2, 10, 10);
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  }
```

```css
body{background-color: blue}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: just finished testing it. works like a charm.  However, I am still trying to understand how your code works with with 4th value for transparent and why data[i+3] and not iterate through each data. Anyway, thanks for giving me a head start!

Comment: ctx.getImageData() does return an imageData object. in this object, there is a property called `data` which is an ArrayBuffer. This ArrayBuffer does contain every red, green, blue and alpha(transparent) values of each pixels. So in this code, I'm iterating through the `data` by 4 (each pixel) and only looking for the alpha value ( `data[ i + 3 ]` ). If I had to check taht the pixel is actually white, I would have done `if(data[i]===data[i+1]===data[i+2]===data[i+3]===255)`

Comment: Ah! gotcha! thanks alot!  It is interesting how this works.